# No 6to4 default route in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, routing, ipv6, 6to4

On my Windows 8.1 laptop, i can’t connect to native IPv6 hosts over 6to4. `route print -6` shows that no default route is set:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 21...02 25 xx xx xx xx ......Karta Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 20...00 25 xx xx xx xx ......Karta Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
 18...00 25 xx xx xx xx ......Urządzenie Bluetooth (sieć osobista)
 17...00 25 xx xx xx xx ......Kontroler sieci NVIDIA nForce
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Karta tunelowania Teredo firmy Microsoft
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Karta Microsoft ISATAP
 24...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Karta Microsoft 6to4
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 22    306 2001::/32                On-link
 22    306 2001:0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128
                                    On-link
 24   1010 2002::/16                On-link
 24    266 2002:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx/128
                                    On-link
 17    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    306 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128
                                    On-link
 17    266 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 17    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I'm aware that i can set the default route manually, but this only works around the problem, which reappears if, for example, the IPv6 stack is reset, which deletes custom routes. On another PC with Vista on it, the 6to4 default route gets set automatically and survives a reset of the IPv6 stack.

What could be causing such behavior?

Comment: Probably because using 6to4 is being deprecated

Comment: @SanderSteffann How? Native IPv6 users are a minority still. And 6to4 actually **works** where i live.

Comment: @SanderSteffann This is definitely not the expected behavior. I noticed by repeatedly running `route print /6` that at first Teredo gets set as the default route, and then as 6to4 gets initialised, it removes the Teredo route but somehow fails to set its own

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-v6ops-6to4-to-historic is being discussed again. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724#appendix-B also specifies that native IPv4 is preferred over relayed 6to4. 6to4 source addresses should only be used to connect to 6to4 destinations. I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft decided to not use 6to4 relays at all anymore. Just like they are looking at [sunsetting Teredo](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/87/slides/slides-87-v6ops-5.pdf)

Comment: Besides, the [low reliability of 6to4](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/emileaben/6to4-how-bad-is-it-really) depends on the 6to4 relay closest to you and also on the 6to4 relay closest to the native IPv6 system you are talking to. Even if the relay you use is good the other relay might still be bad. It is therefore usually better to use a managed tunnel (SixXS, HE/tunnelbroker.net) then you can't get native IPv6 so you know who is managing the devices for your IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: All of this doesn't answer why you don't see a default route using 6to4, but it *might* be that Microsoft is trying to avoid it.

Comment: If 6to4 actually works where you live, you're in an even smaller minority than native IPv6 users. And anyway, [nsayer notes](http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/6to4/) that "Everyone using 6to4 should now set their default router to `2002:c058:6301:`"

Comment: @MichaelHampton 1° not in Poland, AFAIK only two minor local ISPs are offering IPv6 to individual customers, while 6to4 works perfectly on UPC,the #1 cable operator; 2° this is precisely what the Vista computer i have access to is doing automatically.

Comment: @SanderSteffann re managed tunnels: i’m not trying to get IPv6 access for home, but to diagnose a problem with my installation.

Comment: You are still well advised to dump 6to4 and use a tunnel. Even if 6to4 works today, it will not do in the very near future.

Comment: As I explained earlier 6to4 depends not only on your local ISP and closest relay but also on the relay closest to the remote side. Saying "6to4 works perfectly on UPC" doesn't make sense because you're looking at only part of the situation. Not having a default IPv6 route over 6to4 is proper behaviour so your setup is fine. If you want working IPv6 then Michael and I have given you advice on what to do.

Comment: @SanderSteffann “Not having a default IPv6 route over 6to4 is proper behaviour” [citation needed]

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6343 section 4.1 item 2, and lots of experience (search for research done by Emile Aben and Geoff Huston)

Comment: @SanderSteffann This is not proper behavior [This post](http://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic2800590.html#13525351) shows that having a 6to4 route is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: As of December 2014, UPC now directs 192.88.99.1 to Hurricane Electric, so the problem no longer appears for UPC users.

---

The 6to4 anycast relay i get (port80.se) unfortunately has a misconfigured or overzealous firewall.

Windows 8.1 tests 6to4 relay availability by trying to ping `[2002:c058:6301::c058:6301]` with [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) set to 1 and [expecting to get either a response or a TTL exceeded error](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/v6ops/current/msg07626.html), only then enabling a default route to 6to4.

I have emailed the server admins at port80 and will update if i get any response back.

The workarounds include setting a default route manually, or choosing a non-anycast relay.